# suppressing /dev/watchdog system message

Tags: linux, debian, watchdog

I'm triggering linux watchdog every 3 secs.

```
echo 1 > /dev/watchdog >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But I still get following system message:

```
*[  966.695312] watchdog watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!*
```

Is it possible to suppress this message?

Answer (score 4):

The process writing to the watchdog file is expected to keep the `/dev/watchdog` device file open. Your script does not do that.

When a `nowayout` parameter of `1` is set on a watchdog kernel module (such as iTCO_wdt) then when the /dev/watchdog device is closed the "watchdog did not stop" message appears. This reminds system administrators that the watchdog timer is still running and will shortly reboot the machine, even though the watchdog-poking process has stopped.

Either correct your program, consider the *watchdog* package offered by many distributions, or consider configuring Systemd's `RuntimeWatchdogSec`.